# Select distinct column values and add the related of values of another column

Tags: sql-server, distinct

I'm working on a time card system where a user can enter a time against a single unit or a 'run' of units.

I have already created the time entry portion, where a user can enter time against a 'run' and it will create separate rows for each unit specified as being part of that 'run'. It also divides the time they entered (ie. run15 had 8 hours put against it, so each unit would get 4 hours) 
Note that if the time was entered against a single unit, the RunNum is left blank.

```
UnitNum    RunNum       Hours               Date
---        ----         ------            --------
1          12            5                08-01-2013
2          12            5                08-01-2013
3          12            5                08-01-2013
4          -            10                08-02-2013
5          -             8                08-02-2013
6          -             4                08-03-2013
9          15            4                08-03-2013
9          15            4                08-03-2013
1          12            1.5              08-04-2013
2          12            1.5              08-04-2013
3          12            1.5              08-04-2013
```

Now that I am moving on to the editing portion of the system; things are a little more complicated.
Since I don't want the user to have to edit the individual units in the run, i would like it to display as the single run again.

I need combine the distinct runs; add their corresponding hours, where the date is the same; and hide the unitnum:

```
UnitNum    RunNum       Hours               Date
---        ----         ------            --------
-          12           15                08-01-2013
4          -            10                08-02-2013
5          -             8                08-02-2013
6          -             4                08-03-2013
-          15            8                08-03-2013
-          12            4.5              08-04-2013
```

So far, my code grabs everything and looks like this:

```
<?PHP
$EditPickSelect = SQLSRV_QUERY($conn1,"SELECT runnum, unitnum, date, hours FROM dbo.TimecardHours ORDER BY date");
ECHO "<br>";
ECHO "<table border='1'>";

ECHO "<tr>";

ECHO "<td>";
    ECHO "Run";
ECHO "</td>";

ECHO "<td>";
    ECHO "Unit";
ECHO "</td>";

ECHO "<td>";
    ECHO "Hours";
ECHO "</td>";

ECHO "<td>";
    ECHO "Date";
ECHO "</td>";

ECHO "</tr>";


WHILE ($EditPickFetch=SQLSRV_FETCH_ARRAY($EditPickSelect, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{

ECHO "<tr>";

    ECHO "<td>";
    ECHO "<center>";
        if ($EditPickFetch['runnum'] == '') {
        ECHO "-";
        } else {
        ECHO $EditPickFetch['runnum'];
        }
    ECHO "</center>";
    ECHO "</td>";

    ECHO "<td>";
    ECHO "<center>";
        if ($EditPickFetch['unitnum'] == '') {
        ECHO "-";
        } else {
        ECHO $EditPickFetch['unitnum'];
        }
    ECHO "</center>";
    ECHO "</td>";

    ECHO "<td>";
    ECHO "<center>";
        ECHO $EditPickFetch['hours'];
    ECHO "</center>";
    ECHO "</td>";

    ECHO "<td>";
    ECHO "<center>";
        ECHO $EditPickFetch['date'];
    ECHO "</center>";
    ECHO "</td>";

ECHO "</tr>";

}

ECHO "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you.

```
SELECT NULL AS UnitNum, [Runnum], SUM([Hours]), [Date]
FROM [Dbo].Timecardhours
WHERE Runnum IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Date, 
  Runnum
UNION ALL
SELECT UnitNum, [Runnum], SUM([Hours]), [Date]
 FROM [Dbo].Timecardhours
WHERE Runnum IS NULL
GROUP BY Date, 
  Runnum, 
  Unitnum;
```

Comment: This is very close, Dbloch; however, I would like the Unitnum to show if the unit doesn't have a Runnum. Separately, the select statement that handles the Units without a Runnum, can show it; but when they are unionized, it breaks because the run select has to ignore the units to work.

Comment: Edited the select statement, I believe that is what you are asking for.

Comment: That's the key. One needs to have the column in both select statements for the union to work. Since it can't exist in the one select statement, select the column as NULL.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking to just do an aggregation:

```
Select runNum, date, sum(hours) as hours 
from dbo.TimeCardHours 
Group by runNum, date 
order by Date
```